# How to check integers if it is simple -no directed graph with corresponding degree edgees

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I have
two cases.

1)`2,2,2,3,5`

2)`2,2,2,3,3`

for case 1 : as I see if I add **2+2+2+3+5=14** that means it is simple and no directed graph with corresponding degree edges.

for case 2: **2+2+2+3+3 =12** that means it is simple and no directed with corresponding degree edges.

If it wwas  like  1,2,2,2,4 and we have 1+2+2+2+4=11 that means it doesn't be simple.
Did I handle the exercise well?

thanks in advance

Comment: For case 1: suppose we give the vertices names, so that the vertices $v,w,x,y,z$ have degree $2,2,2,3,5$. Which $5$ vertices is $z$ adjacent to?

Comment: @MishaLavrov hi , I am not sure ,it will need the 5 vertices 10 to be adjacent  out of 14 ?

Comment: it has at least two times the 2,  the vertices is even number so does it be simple and no directed graph corresponding degree edges OR it plays a role the 5 ?I know that 2|E| that means 2*14

Comment: You are confusing vertices and edges. This graph should have $\frac{2+2+2+3+5}{2} = 7$ edges; it should have only $5$ vertices.

Comment: yes I confused I see.  First you add  those to find the 14(which is vertices) and you divide with 2 to find edges.Why should it have 5?Instead of 7?can you explain me this

Comment: There are $5$ vertices because you were given $5$ numbers, each of which is the degree of a vertex.

Comment: so it is wrong? the case 2 :  ( 2+2+2+3+3 )  / 2   = 12/2 = 6. It should have and this only 5?

Comment: so both are wrong?(I mean case 1 and case 2 )

Comment: You are confusing vertices and edges again. Just because a graph has $5$ vertices does not mean it must have $5$ edges.

Comment: for case 1 : as I see if I add 2+2+2+3+5=14 that means it is simple and no directed graph with corresponding degree vertices.

for case 2: 2+2+2+3+3 =12 that means it is simple and no directed with corresponding degree vertices.

Comment: now am I right?